# How I can compare histograms using statistical tests?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I would like to compare histograms using statistical tests.
Every histograms have 5 classes. For example:
[image]

I think, that I can use kolmogorov-smirnov test. Is it the correct way? What other statistical tests I should use?
Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Compare what about the plots?

Answer (score 3):

The two 'histograms' are just one of several ways to display two samples.
It would be more appropriate to ask whether the two samples differ,
perhaps showing that they were sampled from different populations.

If vertical axes on your histograms (or are they bar charts?) are frequencies,
then you might want to put the counts into a $2\times 5$ contingency table.
Something like:

```
TAB = rbind(c(151,902,273,258, 84), c(371, 1110, 163, 172, 22))
TAB 
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]  151  902  273  258   84
[2,]  371 1110  163  172   22
```

And then do a chi-squared test of homogeneity, to find that
the two sets of counts are unlikely to have come from the same population--on
account of the P-vale very near $0.$

```
chisq.test(TAB)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  TAB
X-squared = 187.64, df = 4, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

The chi-squared test is used to compare *nominal categories.* If bins 1 through 5 designate *numbers* or *ordinal categories,* then
other tests, using that additional information, might be used.